# How to output JSON array in HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, json

I use ECWID for my website store and am wanting to create some code, to do that i have to do some JSON requests and i have never worked with JSON. When i type the following into my address bar:
http://app.ecwid.com/api/v1/STOREID/product?id=PRODUCTID
ofcourse replacing storeid and productid with numbers referencing to my store and the specific product i get a text return of

```
{
  "id": 8443685,
  "sku": "KEN000025",
  "smallThumbnailUrl": "picture URL here",
  "thumbnailUrl": "thumbnail URL here",
  "imageUrl": "image URL here",
  "name": "Kenwood Excelon KFC-X173",
  "price": 99.99,
  "weight": 1.0,
  "url": "long URL here",
  "description": "long description here",
  "options": [],
  "taxes": [],
  "galleryImages": [],
  "categories": [
    {
      "id": 769355,
      "thumbnailUrl": "url here",
      "name": "Speakers",
      "url": "url here",
      "description": ""
    },
    {
      "id": 1466304,
      "parentId": 1466305,
      "thumbnailUrl": "URL here",
      "name": "Kenwood",
      "url": "URL here",
      "description": ""
    }
  ],
  "dateAdded": 1325037351
}
```

Now if i have an HTML document and i want to output the picture of an item then below that the price of it how would i do that using the information from the JSON link.

PS i know Java script HTML PHP XML and a lot of other languages just not JSON
Thank you

Comment: So, you want to do that in javascript? php?

Comment: javascript would work thanks for your reply

Comment: did any of the solutions work out for you?

Answer (score 3):

### How to use JSON in PHP

JSON is very simple, yet powerful format for exchanging information.

If you want to process the JSON string you fetched (and stored eg. in `$json` variable), you do it simply by:

```
$decoded_json = json_decode($json, true);
```

(remove the second parameter or replace by `false` if instead of associative arrays you want objects) and then you process it as a simple or multidimensional array. To change it back into string just do `$json = json_encode($decoded_json);`.

Your decoded JSON string can be seen here: http://codepad.org/ZARAK3Er

### Getting values from JSON

To output thumbnail URL and price in your case just use the following (do not forget to output `$thumbnailUrl` and `$price` appropriately - the snippet below just assigns value to them):

```
$decoded_json = json_decode($json, true);
$thumbnailUrl = $decoded_json['thumbnailUrl'];
$price = $decoded_json['price'];
```

See proof here: http://codepad.org/5BKi9sPp

### Fetching external JSON file

To fetch external JSON file into the `$json` string use `file_get_contents()`. In your case it could look like this:

```
$url = 'http://app.ecwid.com/api/v1/STOREID/product?id=PRODUCTID';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
```

### Solution

What you want can be achieved by gluing all the parts discussed above:

```
$url = 'http://app.ecwid.com/api/v1/STOREID/product?id=PRODUCTID';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$decoded_json = json_decode($json, true);
$thumbnailUrl = $decoded_json['thumbnailUrl'];
$price = $decoded_json['price'];
```

As a result, you will have `$thumbnailUrl` and `$price` variables with the data you want. You can also enclose it within a function, that will take store ID and product ID and return object or associative array containing thumbnail URL and price for the specified product within specified store.

Comment: Okay that makes sense now, so do i have to actually paste the JSON text into the code every time or is there a way that the data can be pulled directly from a URL instead?

Comment: @Timmer1992: Yes, there is a way to fetch the JSON and assign it to `$json` variable of course. What PHP framework do you use?

Comment: @Timmer1992: If you use PHP framework, refer to its documentation - there should (may) be some helper for performing external requests. In raw PHP you can use eg. [`file_get_contents()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) like that: `$json = file_get_contents($url);` (where `$url` is the string containing the URL you want to fetch).

Answer (score 1):

For a recursive way, assume I want to output as `<table>` with bootstrap classes:

```
public static function jsonViewable($jsonText = '')
{
    $arr  = json_decode($jsonText, true);
    $html = "";
    if ($arr && is_array($arr)) {
        $html .= self::_arrayToHtmlTableRecursive($arr);
    }

    return $html;
}

private static function _arrayToHtmlTableRecursive($arr)
{
    $str = "<table class='table table-bordered'><tbody>";
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        $str .= "<tr>";
        $str .= "<td>$key</td>";
        $str .= "<td>";
        if (is_array($val)) {
            if (!empty($val)) {
                $str .= self::_arrayToHtmlTableRecursive($val);
            }
        } else {
            $str .= "<strong>$val</strong>";
        }
        $str .= "</td></tr>";
    }
    $str .= "</tbody></table>";

    return $str;
}
```

Now a call to `myclass::jsonViewable($jsonString)` will have a nice output.
Enjoy,

Answer (score 0):

You can decode the JSON with PHP, which will turn it into associative arrays which you can then iterate through to display the data:

You should be able to use something like:

```
$productArray = json_decode( $JSON_DATA_VARIABLE, true );
$productImageOne = $productArray['categories'][0]['thumbnailUrl'];
$productImageTwo = $productArray['categories'][1]['thumbnailUrl'];
$price = $productArray['price'];
```

You will have to set the JSON data to a variable before you can decode it. I'm sure that example isn't 100% correct (I'm not great at going through arrays without a working example), but you get the idea.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: so how would i link that to the JSON url? so that if i rewrite that data and pass different URL's to it depending on the item it will still output say a box with a picture of the item in it and the price below that. I dont quite understand how to apply this to output the code from my JSON URL